# Can we add credit/debit cards through paypal rest apis

Tags: react-native, paypal, credit-card

I tried to find apis in paypal documentation but not found so is it possible to add cards through paypal REST APIs

Comment: Add to what? A PayPal account? Or simply store (vault) a customer's card for future use?

Comment: I want to add cards to simple vault and also can I edit that card through paypal rest APIs. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for PayPal vault. To process cards with it, activate Advanced Credit and Debit Cards on the live account and use the `payment_source` object of a v2/checkout/orders request